# Setting up a proxy on RHEL5 to improve internet speed for a Windows 7 client?

Tags: windows-7, proxy, rhel-5

Alright here's the problem, it seems like unless I download from anywhere accept my remote dedicated server, speeds are horrible like 50kbps. But if I download from my server it's like 2mbps.

So I want to be able to set up a proxy that will allow me to use the internet routing through my dedicated server which is running RHEL5.

The OS I'm using as a client is Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired effect, you should use a VPN instead of a Proxy as a proxy server is more for filtering out information.

A good semi-free solution is [OpenVpn](http://www.openvpn.net).

It is quite easy to install and setup for both the server and clients.